# Validate blank space with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following script

```
document.getElementById('url').onkeypress = function (e) {
  var val = this.value;
  var validaterror = document.getElementById('errorvalidate');
  if (e.which == 13) {
    if (!/\S/.test(val)) {
        validaterror.innerHTML = 'Please enter domain names in the field.';
        return false;
      }
    validaterror.innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="url"></textarea>
```

And when i don't have any values entered it will work and echo me a message, but if i enter a value and after that hit enter again for going to the next row and leave space on the second row it won't validate anymore. Example: I enter value 123, after i hit enter to go to next row and if i don't enter any value in the next row and hit enter i should get the message "Please enter domain names, but doesn't happen. Please correct me when i am wrong. I assume that i am some where here wrong:

```
if (e.which == 13) {
  if (!/\S/.test(val)) {
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/zBkXw/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `!/\S/.test(val)` to `/^\s*$/m.test(val)`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pQ9wP/

Explanation: `/^\s*$/m` is a regular expression that will match if there is a line that contains only whitespace anywhere in the string.  The `m` (multiline) flag makes it so that `^` will match at the beginning of the string or just after a line break, and the `$` flag will match at the end of the string or just before a line break.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('url').onkeypress = function (e) {
    var val = this.value.split('\n');
    var validaterror = document.getElementById('errorvalidate');
    var i;
    if (e.which == 13) {
        for (i = 0 ; i < val.length ; i++) {
            if (/\s/.test(val[i])) {
                validaterror.innerHTML = 'Please enter domain names in the field.';
                return false;
            }
        }
        validaterror.innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

What I did:

Changed `!/\S/.test` to `/\s/.test`

Split the val on new line characters and evaluate each line against the regex (although it's  also possible to do it with a single multiline regex like F.J is trying to do, but his answer is not working for me)

Comment: It works but from the second row, first row doesn't get's validated anymore.

Comment: You're right, I didn't totally understand your question. I changed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/zBkXw/7/ it should work well enough.

```
var oldkey = null;    
document.getElementById('url').onkeypress = function (e) {
  var val = this.value;
  var validaterror = document.getElementById('errorvalidate');
  if (e.which == 13) {
    if (!/\S/.test(val) || oldkey == e.which) {
        validaterror.innerHTML = 'Please enter domain names in the field.';
        return false;
      }
    validaterror.innerHTML = '';
  }
  oldkey = e.which
}
```

Comment: This allows lines that only contain spaces.

Comment: @F.J You could do this `&& oldkey != 32` but that would mean typing in "domain.com " would be disallowed and while it would be okay for this use case (domain names shouldnt have spaces) your solution is far less hackish and cleaner.